# QVector find QPushButton by their name using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, containers

I have a function which create QPushButtons

```
void MainWindow::createButton(QFrame *parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, QString txt) {
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(parent);
    button->setGeometry(x,y,w,h);
    button->setText(txt);
    button->setObjectName("pushButton_" + txt);
    vecButtons.push_back(button);
}
```

In the mainwindow constructor I would like to connect the push buttons, thus I have to find push button.

**Is there a generic searching algorithm?**

Comment: You probably want to start by looking at [`QWidget::findChild`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild) or one of the [`QWidget::findChildren`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) overloads.  Or... just connect the `QPushButton` instances as/when you create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even though you can find an object by its name like doing:

```
QPushButton *button = parentWidget->findChild<QPushButton *>("pushButton_" + txt);
```

the hasrd thing with this approach is that you need to keep a record of how the buttons are named...

it would be better if you do as suggested in the comments, connect in the createButton method

```
void MainWindow::createButton(QFrame *parent, int x, int y, int w, int h, QString txt) {
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(parent);
    button->setGeometry(x,y,w,h);
    button->setText(txt);
    button->setObjectName("pushButton_" + txt);
    connect(button, somesignal, this, someSlot);   //here
    vecButtons.push_back(button);
}
```